# Is there an idiomatic term for Shopaholic?

Tags: idioms, english-comparison, translation

I write a diary entry in Italian each day to practice my vocabulary and sentence structure. Currently, my theme is 'Chi sono?' so I am looking for words that describe me. Today, I want to write about shopping and would like to know what an Italian who is addicted to shopping would be called. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: si usa dire 'ha le mani bucate' di chi continua a spendere per acquistare, anche senza una reale necessita'.

Comment: Grazie, rosco - una risposta interessante.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A medical term is [oniomaniaco/a](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/oniomaniaco/), from [oniomania](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/oniomania/), with a clear Greek etymology. Only, it is not very common.

You might find it disappointing, but the most popular term is [shopping-dipendente](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/shopping-dipendente_(Neologismi)/) or … [shopaholic](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/shopaholic_(Neologismi)/), both derived from English. You may also try to use "acquistomaniaco/a", derived from [acquistomania](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/acquistomania_(Neologismi)/), only in playful, ironic contexts though.

Probably the best alternatives are "oniomaniaco/a" and "shopping-dipendente".

Comment: Grazie mille! Una risposta dettagliata!

Comment: I wouldn't suggest "oniomaniaco". As a native Italian speaker, I never heard of such a word, and I wouldn't have understood it if someone mentioned it in a conversation. *Shopping-dipendente* is the most common term, and [imho] what a native speaker would write in their diary; I find the other words you suggested to be extremely uncommon.

Comment: Giulio, these are all neologisms, often used only in extremely special occasions - their use is so rare that [Google Books Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oniomaniaco%2Cshopping+dipendente%2Cshopaholic%2Cacquistomaniaco&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2014&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) can't find any of them, at all, not even a single spurious occurrence :-)

Comment: On the contrary, look at the word [shopaholic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shopaholic&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cshopaholic%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bshopaholic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BShopaholic%3B%2Cc0) from the English corpus: it has been increasingly used at least since 1980.

Answer (score 2):

As this would no doubt be a "cool" word, I have no doubt in my mind that most Italians would say "shopaholic"—assuming they understood what it meant.

You hear people say "lo shopping" instead of their own (Italian) word, come on.

Comment: *Shopaholic* is an acceptable word, but in my experience few people are proficient enough in English for them to be aware of the meaning of the suffix "-holic".